# Why does Wget change the encoding of the file content in the HTML file?

Tags: wget

When I use Wget to recursively download a website it seems to break the JavaScript code.

What the original website displays:

```
var exportUrl = "/2020/excel/export.xls?pageId=146&amp;tableIndex=" + tableindex + "&amp;filename=excelexport.xls";

var alias = "Note 15 - Markedsrisiko knyttet til valutaeksponering";
var excelLink = '<a class="excelExport trackDownload excelDownload" data-downloadtype="excel" data-title="' + alias + '" data-tabellindex="' + (tableindex + 1) + '" href="' + exportUrl + '">Eksporter til Excel</a>';
```

What I get:

```
var exportUrl = "/2020/excel/export.xls?pageId=146&amp;tableIndex=" + tableindex + "&amp;filename=excelexport.xls";

var alias = "Note 15 - Markedsrisiko knyttet til valutaeksponering";
var excelLink = '<a class="excelExport trackDownload excelDownload" data-downloadtype="excel" data-title="' + alias + '" data-tabellindex="' + (tableindex + 1) + '" href="https://aarsrapport.smn.no/2020/note_markedsrisiko_valuta/'&#32;+&#32;exportUrl&#32;+&#32;'">Eksporter til Excel</a>';
                    $table.after(excelLink);
```

Note the difference between the `href`, this is where the difference is.
`href="' + exportUrl + '"` vs `href="https://aarsrapport.smn.no/2020/note_markedsrisiko_valuta/'&#32;+&#32;exportUrl&#32;+&#32;'"`

**I want** `+ exportUrl +` **and not** `&#32;+&#32;exportUrl&#32;+&#32;`

It seems like the `+` character is encoded to its encoding `&#32`. How can I make Wget not do this? Furthermore, the recursive download is affected by this since the `&#32` URLs don't exists.

This is my Wget command:

```
data_dir="test_data"
mkdir $data_dir

urls="https://aarsrapport.smn.no/2020/"

wget --recursive --level=inf --page-requisites --adjust-extension --convert-links --no-parent --restrict-file-names=ascii --remote-encoding=utf-8 --directory-prefix="$data_dir" $urls
```

I have tried with `--restrict-file-names=nocontrol`, `--remote-encoding=utf-8`, `--local-encoding=utf-8` and more without success.

(Note that the affected URLs points to Excel files, could this be the issue?)

Comment: `&#32;` encodes a space character. Maybe don't put spaces around `+`-characters, i.e. instead of `+ '" href="' + exportUrl + '` try just `+ '" href="'+exportUrl+'`.

Comment: You are correct, `&#32` encodes a space character. However, I did not make the website so I do not have control of the `href` content. I just need to scrape the content, but Wget seem to modify it.

Comment: I don't think Wget is meant to parse Javascript at all. It parses only basic HTML markup.

Comment: You are right, it does not parse JavaScript. I have found this to be a limitation of Wget since the parts of a website that is built with JavaScript is misunderstood by Wget.